# How to restart jquery delay.fadeout

Tags: jquery, delay, fadeout

When a user clicks a button, we do a

```
$('#element').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

If they click the button within 5 seconds, we would like to restart the effect, but as it is written now, the first one completes and the second effect does not happen.

Comment: Not really clear what expected behavior is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `finish()` to make the previous action play to completion immediately. Ref. http://api.jquery.com/finish/

```js
$('#target').on('click', function(){
  $('#element').finish().show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#element {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target">Do It</button>
<div id="element">Element</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the official doc, https://api.jquery.com/delay/, the delay is not cancelable :

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

You have to use a timeout instead :

```js
var myTimer;
$('#stop').on('click', function(){
    $('#tohide').show();
     clearTimeout(myTimer);
});
$('#show').on('click', function(){
   $('#tohide').show();
    myTimer = setTimeout(function(){$('#tohide').fadeOut();}, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="tohide" style="display:none">to hide</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="show">show</button>
```